# Grouping multiple queries on same table , TQSL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, union

I have a rather large table of inormation that needs to be filtered differently for several different work departments.  I created the below query that returns the same number of columns so that they should be able to be UNION'd up.  I want to make sure no duplicate rows are returned, hence the reason I used UNION, however I keep getting the error "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
Column 'ACT_DW.dbo.INV-ACT.DNUM' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
Anyone see the issue here?  What I am looking to get is just one big table of all the records grouped by the Deskname field per Workgroup if possible.

```
    declare @InventoryAsOfEOD date,
        @Start date,
        @End date   


SET @Start = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()),0) AS DATE)
SET @End = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()))), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())) as DATE)

IF
    DATENAME(DW, GETDATE()) = 'Monday'
BEGIN
    Set @InventoryAsOfEOD = CAST(DATEADD(D, -3, GETDATE())AS DATE) 
END
ELSE
    Set @InventoryAsOfEOD = CAST(DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)

print @inventoryasofeod
print @start
print @end



SELECT 
    DNUM,
    SSN,
    DTRFIRSTNAME,
    DTRLASTNAME,
    ASSIGNDATE,
    [DESK],
    Deskname,
    PYMTAMT1,
    DueDate,
    PnI,
    PIBALATSETUP,
    Ttl_Balance,
    pmgroup,
    PROGTYPE,
    office,
    client,
    batch,
    placetype,
    pymtdt1,
    Ttl_Starts

FROM

(SELECT 
    DNUM,
    SSN,
    DTRFIRSTNAME,
    DTRLASTNAME,
    ASSIGNDATE,
    [DESK],
    Deskname,
    PYMTAMT1,
    PROGSTARTDT as DueDate,
    sum([Prinbal]+[INTBAL]) as PnI,
    PIBALATSETUP,
    BALANCE as Ttl_Balance,
    pmgroup,
    PROGTYPE,
    office,
    client,
    batch,
    placetype,
    pymtdt1,
    COUNT(SSN) as Ttl_Starts

FROM 
    [ACT_DW].[dbo].[INV-ACT] with(INDEX([IX_INV-ACT_InventoryAsOfEOD]),nolock)
WHERE 
    InventoryAsOfEOD = @InventoryAsOfEOD AND
    BC ='GSL' AND
    PROGTYPE not in('PMT PLAN', 'Fallout', 'PIF', 'SIF') AND
    PROGTYPE is not null and
    PYMTDT1 BETWEEN @Start AND @End


UNION 
--Get Oregon Starts

SELECT 
    DNUM,
    SSN,
    DTRFIRSTNAME,
    DTRLASTNAME,
    ASSIGNDATE,
    [DESK],
    Deskname,
    PYMTAMT1,
    PROGSTARTDT as DueDate,
    sum([Prinbal]+[INTBAL]) as PnI,
    PIBALATSETUP,
    BALANCE as Ttl_Balance,
    pmgroup,
    PROGTYPE,
    office,
    client,
    batch,
    placetype,
    pymtdt1,
    COUNT(SSN) as Ttl_Starts

FROM 
    [ACT_DW].[dbo].[INV-ACT] with(INDEX([IX_INV-ACT_InventoryAsOfEOD]),nolock)
WHERE
    InventoryAsOfEOD = @InventoryAsOfEOD and
    CLIENT like 'ORDOR%' and    
    PROGTYPE not in ('Null', 'Fallout') AND
    PYMTDT1 BETWEEN @Start AND @End


UNION 
--Get Perkins Starts

SELECT 
    DNUM,
    SSN,
    DTRFIRSTNAME,
    DTRLASTNAME,
    ASSIGNDATE,
    [DESK],
    Deskname,
    PYMTAMT1,
    PROGSTARTDT as DueDate,
    sum([Prinbal]+[INTBAL]) as PnI,
    PIBALATSETUP,
    BALANCE as Ttl_Balance,
    pmgroup,
    PROGTYPE,
    office,
    client,
    batch,
    placetype,
    pymtdt1,
    COUNT(SSN) as Ttl_Starts
FROM
    [ACT_DW].[dbo].[INV-ACT] with(INDEX([IX_INV-ACT_InventoryAsOfEOD]),nolock)
WHERE
    InventoryAsOfEOD = @InventoryAsOfEOD and
    BC in ('PE1', 'PE2', 'PE3', 'NU1', 'NU2', 'NDS') and
    PROGTYPE not in ('Null', 'Fallout') AND
    PYMTDT1 BETWEEN @Start AND @End

UNION 

--Get starts for Tuition

SELECT 
    DNUM,
    SSN,
    DTRFIRSTNAME,
    DTRLASTNAME,
    ASSIGNDATE,
    [DESK],
    Deskname,
    PYMTAMT1,
    PROGSTARTDT as DueDate,
    sum([Prinbal]+[INTBAL]) as PnI,
    PIBALATSETUP,
    BALANCE as Ttl_Balance,
    pmgroup,
    PROGTYPE,
    office,
    client,
    batch,
    placetype,
    pymtdt1,
    COUNT(SSN) as Ttl_Starts
FROM
    [ACT_DW].[dbo].[INV-ACT] with(INDEX([IX_INV-ACT_InventoryAsOfEOD]),nolock)
WHERE
    InventoryAsOfEOD = @InventoryAsOfEOD and
    BC in ('AR1', 'AR2', 'IN1', 'IN2', 'IN3', 'TU1', 'TU2', 'TU3') and
    PROGTYPE not in ('Null', 'Fallout') AND
    PYMTDT1 BETWEEN @Start AND @End

UNION 

--Get Starts for Chase

SELECT 
    DNUM,
    SSN,
    DTRFIRSTNAME,
    DTRLASTNAME,
    ASSIGNDATE,
    [DESK],
    Deskname,
    PYMTAMT1,
    PROGSTARTDT as DueDate,
    sum([Prinbal]+[INTBAL]) as PnI,
    PIBALATSETUP,
    BALANCE as Ttl_Balance,
    pmgroup,
    PROGTYPE,
    office,
    client,
    batch,
    placetype,
    pymtdt1,
    COUNT(SSN) as Ttl_Starts
FROM
    [ACT_DW].[dbo].[INV-ACT] with(INDEX([IX_INV-ACT_InventoryAsOfEOD]),nolock)
WHERE
    InventoryAsOfEOD = @InventoryAsOfEOD and
    CLIENT like 'AG%' and
    PROGTYPE not in ('Null', 'Fallout') AND
    PYMTDT1 BETWEEN @Start AND @End) 
    as StartsTable

GROUP BY 
    DNUM,
    SSN,
    DTRFIRSTNAME,
    DTRLASTNAME,
    ASSIGNDATE,
    PYMTAMT1,
    DueDate,
    PIBALATSETUP,
    Ttl_Balance,
    PROGTYPE,
    DESK,
    deskname,
    PMGROUP,
    OFFICE,
    CLIENT,
    BATCH,
    PLACETYPE,
    PYMTDT1
ORDER BY 
    PMGROUP,
    DESK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include your `GROUP BY` clause for each subquery which includes aggregates.  You could instead union rows and *then* aggregate, but that would be a different query.

Comment: Hmm- that worked (group by in the each subquery)!  Thanks for the help, I'm a newbie at SQL, sometimes it's just the smallest things...